# Best tool - Show source codes - Web

Tags: asp.net

What is the best tool for showing source codes on the Web ?

with Syntax highlighting , in color - Line-Numbers
Asp.Net

Comment: Presumably you wish to take a C# source file and render it in HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display source code on a web page, a search for "syntax highlighter" will give you a few suggestions.

[Scott Hanselman has an article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BestCodeSyntaxHighlighterForSnippetsInYourBlog.aspx) on what he uses on his blog. Its a javascript one, and it (almost) only requires you to include the correct js files... (Easy read, and seems like a good solution.)

Comment: That is the thing that I've been looking for , thx

Answer (score 1):

Is [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) what you're looking for?

From the main page:

> GeSHi started as an idea to create a
> generic syntax highlighter for the
> phpBB forum system, but has been
> generalised to this project. GeSHi
> aims to be a simple but powerful
> highlighting class, with the following
> goals:
>
> - Support for a wide range of popular languages
> - Easy to add a new language for highlighting
> - Highly customisable output formats
>
> GeSHi supports PHP5 and Windows, and has even been used to highlight code on ASP pages.

Comment: It should be a good thing also , thx

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET, Visual Studio seems quite popular.

If you just want to see the source of the generated HTML, rather than create and edit the server side code, Firefox with Firebug works nicely.